# How Do i restore FormBorderStyle non form at onclick

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i'm beginner.  my form border style is none i want to restore it only one click which event should i use to restore it in one click..

my Code

```
    private void New_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not 'which event should i use?' It is : 'What should the user do?' Click? Where?? Your choice..

Comment: it's not appearing at onclick

Comment: ? what is 'onclick' ?? what is 'New_Click' ??? What is 'not appearing' ? If you want help you should be a lot clearer and more explicit! __Is, God forbid,  'New' the name of your form???__ In that case you have not hooked it up. Nor coded for the Borderstyle to change..

Comment: Onclick of which control? `Form` or what control?

Comment: what should i do to restore it at onclick

Comment: New is name of my form..

Comment: `Onclick` of which particular control?

Comment: OnClick of form @Rahul

Comment: What you want to restore to? your current border style is `None`?

Comment: i want to restore  my minimize form.. @Rahul and yup my current border style is non

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hook up (Register) the `Form/controls Click` event and perform whatever you want in the handler method. Like below

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Click +=new EventHandler(Form1_Click);
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```